# Clicking on preference screen does not attach preference fragment

Tags: android, preferencefragment

I have a settings activity with a ListPreference and a PreferenceScreen. These two 
Preferences are loaded using a PreferenceFragment. When the PreferenceScreen 
is clicked, a second PreferenceFragment, which holds a list of other Preferences,
 replaces the first PreferenceFragment. The 2nd fragment is correctly loaded
 but not attached to the activity. When I press the back button the 2nd fragment
is correctly displayed in the activity's framework, which is the desired action
but achieved after pressing the back button and not after pressing the
 PreferenceScreen.

Here's the SettingsActivity code:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {

private static String TAG = "SettingsActivity";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

    setContentView(R.layout.settings);
    Log.i(TAG, "SettingsActivity called");

    if(findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
        if(savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, 
                new SettingsFragment()).commit();
    }
}




public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings_preference);  



        PreferenceScreen ps = (PreferenceScreen) getPreferenceManager().findPreference("nots");
        ps.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                SettingsFragment1 sf1 = new SettingsFragment1();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, sf1);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                //transaction.attach(sf1); this proved to be redundant
                transaction.commit();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }       
}


public static class SettingsFragment1 extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings1_preference); 

    }
}
```

}

What could possibly be wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem was that in the `preference.xml` file, the `PreferenceScreen` tag was fully deployed with other preferences, the ones that were supposed to be loaded with the second preference fragment. So by clicking on the `PreferenceScreen`, the latter was loaded with its preferences as if it was not hosted in a fragment. I just removed the preferences below the `PreferenceScreen` and left it on its own.

It's a strange thing that a problem's solution may just come up, as soon as you state it.